# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^3}{e^x +y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> The curve $f(x,y)=0$ passes through $(0,2)$ and satisfies
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^3}{e^x +y^2}$$
> The line $x=\ln 5$ intersects the curve at $y=a$ and $y=b$. Find the value of $\frac{4(a^2+b^2)}{53}$

It is the differential equation that I'm unable to crack. I'm almost sure that it is reducible to a Linear Differential Equation.

My futile attempts include:

- Homogeneous form/reducible to homogeneous form
- Linear Differential treating $x$ as independent variable

I am also toying with the idea that here $y$ could be the independent variable but I'm unable to proceed.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint $(1/y^2+e^{-x})dy=e^{-x}ydx \implies dy/y^2 = -d(e^{-x}y)$

Comment: (+1) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=\frac{y^3}{e^x +y^2}$$
It's Bernoulli's differential equation. Substitute $u=e^x$
$$ u\dfrac {dy}{du}=\frac{y^3}{u +y^2}$$
$$ u({u +y^2})=u'{y^3}$$
$$u'=\dfrac uy+\dfrac {u^2}{y^3}$$

Comment: (+1) Wow. Wasn't expecting this. Thank you very much. Since user600016 posted an answer before yours, I'll accept that one. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar You're welcome. Yes no problem User600016 's answer is a nice one .